# What cube roots are constructible using compass and MARKED straightedge?

Tags: geometric-construction

DUE DILIGENCE: I have reviewed the list of questions possibly related to the one that I pose below, and I find that none of them address my particular question.

Is there a formal definition for the class of non-cubic integers whose cube roots are constructible using a compass and a MARKED straightedge?

If such a class exists, then $2$ would be a member of it. Are there other known members not derivable from $2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, cube root of any number $k$ can be constructed given an interval of length $k$, marked ruler and compass. See [here](https://haeld.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/neusis-classical-geometry-with-more-than-just-ruler-and-compass/) for such a construction along with a proof.